# Cancelling Alarm Manager in Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am having some problem when trying to cancel AlarmManager in Android. I am calling this retrieveBudget() onCreate:

```
public void retrieveBudget() {
    txtDisplayMonthlyExpenses = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayMonthlyExpense);
    txtDisplayBudget = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayBudget);
    cbDisplayReminderNotify = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbDisplayReminderNotify);
    cbDisplayReminderNotify.setEnabled(false);

    DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();
    TransactionRecController trc = new TransactionRecController(
            mDbHelper.open());
    currentMonthExpense = trc.getThisMonthDebit();
    txtDisplayMonthlyExpenses.setText("$ "
            + formatter.format(currentMonthExpense));

    BudgetController bc = new BudgetController(mDbHelper.open());

    BudgetModel bm = bc.getBudget();
    if (bm.getBudgetAmount() != 0 && bm.getReminderNotify() != null) {
        budget = bm.getBudgetAmount();
        txtDisplayBudget.setText("$ " + formatter.format(budget));
        if (bm.getReminderNotify().equals("Y")) {
            cbDisplayReminderNotify.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            cbDisplayReminderNotify.setChecked(false);
        }
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pi = null;
        if (bm.getReminderNotify().equals("Y")
                && currentMonthExpense > budget) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
            notificationCount = notificationCount + 1;

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                    BudgetAlarm.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("NotifyCount", notificationCount);
            pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationCount,
                    notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, pi);
        } else {
            mgr.cancel(pi);
        }
    } else {
        txtDisplayBudget.setText("No budget record yet");
    }

    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

And inside my budgetAlarm class, it just simply setting the notification. So my problem is it did execute the notification every minute. But after I changed my reminderNotify to "N" instead of "Y", it does not cancel the alarm manager. I wonder why is it so because after my update SQL statement, I am calling this retrieveBudget() again.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

These are the codes where I update the budget part. I am calling the the retrieveBudget() once again when the Okay from dialogue box was clicked.

```
public void onEditBudgetClicked(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder EditDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    EditDialog.setTitle("Edit Budget");

    // Get the components from XML file
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.edit_budget, null);
    txtEditBudgetAmount = (EditText) dialogView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtEditBudgetAmount);
    cbEditReminderNotify = (CheckBox) dialogView
            .findViewById(R.id.cbEditReminderNotify);

    // Retrieve budget record
    DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();
    BudgetController bc = new BudgetController(mDbHelper.open());
    BudgetModel bm = bc.getBudget();
    if (bm.getBudgetAmount() != 0 && bm.getReminderNotify() != null) {
        txtEditBudgetAmount.setText(Float.toString(bm.getBudgetAmount()));
        if (bm.getReminderNotify().equals("Y")) {
            cbEditReminderNotify.setChecked(true);
            editReminderNotify = "Y";
        } else {
            cbEditReminderNotify.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    mDbHelper.close();

    cbEditReminderNotify.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (cbEditReminderNotify.isChecked()) {
                editReminderNotify = "Y";
            } else {
                editReminderNotify = "N";
            }
        }
    });

    EditDialog.setView(dialogView);
    EditDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    onEditBudgetSubmitClicked();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    retrieveBudget();
                }
            });

    EditDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    EditDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Your pi is initialized to null, also if you want to cancel you have to recreate your pending intent and then send it through cancel on the AlarmManager

Comment: Alright so I just copy the four lines of code over?

Comment: Yes make sure that it will be the same as the one you sent!

Comment: Hold on, let me modify and test it. :)

Comment: @Pavlos Unfortunately, it does not work. It still executing the alarm manager

Comment: If you are using System.currentTimeMillis your pending Intents will never be the exact same so you wont be able to cancel them i guess

Comment: So is there any other ways to fix this?

Comment: Can you post your whole code after the change?

Comment: Where is your alarm code gone? :P

Comment: @Pavlos Sorry but what do you mean? The code in edited portion will call the first part of the code again. And the AlarmManager is inside

Comment: I dont get you! When i told you you need to recreate the pending intent i mean exact recreation. In the first post of code you need to copy paste the code from if inside the else too! Try that!

Comment: Sorry but I am kind of lost. Would you mind to post me the solution as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of notification count used while initializing the pending intent at the time creation and cancellation of the alarm manager should be same.

Use same value of requestFalg in the pending intent.

Replace this part:

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pi = null;
if (bm.getReminderNotify().equals("Y")
           && currentMonthExpense > budget) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    notificationCount = notificationCount + 1;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                BudgetAlarm.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("NotifyCount", notificationCount);
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationCount,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, pi);
    } else {
        mgr.cancel(pi);
    }
```

with

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                BudgetAlarm.class);
PendingIntent pi = null;
if (bm.getReminderNotify().equals("Y")
            && currentMonthExpense > budget) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    notificationCount = notificationCount + 1;
    notificationIntent.putExtra("NotifyCount", notificationCount);
    pi= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, pi);
    } else {
        pi= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mgr.cancel(pi);
    }
```

if you changed the value of requestFlag (in your case notificationcount)while initializing the pending intent after launching the alarm, you won't be able to cancel it.

**Use same value of requestFlag in the pending intent while creating and cancelling the alarm. Here, I am using 1.**

Since you are changing the value of notificationFlag after launching the alarm manager, don't use notificationFlag as a requestFlag. Use a constant integer value as a requestFlag while initializing **pi** inside both if and else part.

**pi= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, CONSTANT_INTEGER,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);**

check the link below:

**PendingIntent getBroadcast (Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29

Comment: So you mean I should put it after declaring the PendingIntent and before the if statement?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more? I am still confused

Comment: Okay sure thanks a lot! So for my case I should replace your 1 with notificationCount? Also, why are you using 1? Sorry I was abit confused

Comment: Let me test it again :)

Comment: But in my budgetAlarm class, I put this: PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    new Intent(), 0); Do I need to change the 0 to 1?

Comment: @IWasSoLost if you are dealing with the same pending intent, then use the same format as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: One last question, let's say I got more than one receiver in the project and the pending intent for this case I am using 1. So I should use 0,2 and so on for other pending intent so that it wont be mixed up?

Comment: @IWasSoLost if the intent inside the pending-intent is different, then it might not be a problem. But, just to be on the safe side, use a different requestFlag value for that pending intent.

Comment: Okay! Thanks a lot! But for that case if I set the same request flag, it wont run so I have to set it as notificationCount

Comment: @IWasSoLost if you are going to cancel that new pending intent later, and you also want to use the value of notificationCount as a requestFlag, then store the value of notificationCount(that you used while initializing the new pending intent) to some static integer variable so that can use it while cancelling that pending intent later.

Comment: Okay sure thanks a lot! But for this case, every time when I run the apps, it will execute the alarm manager and prompt notification. Is there any way to do it like it will only prompt the notification once per day when it meets the requirement and no matter how many time I launch the apps

Comment: @IWasSoLost use some boolean flag in the shared preference, to check whether the notification was already fired or not, before showing the notification. That way, even if the alarm-manager is running, it won't show the notification.

Comment: Would you mind to post me the solution? because I wasn't quite clear about what you mentioned above.

Comment: @IWasSoLost I haven't tried that method. I just gave you the idea. Need to go through the internet more for that.

Comment: Hey can you help me take a look at my another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098284/android-alarm-manager-repeating-tasks I've followed your guide to set the same for request flag but somehow it does not work

Comment: Can you please help me take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102164/alarm-manager-not-running-in-background

Answer (score 0):

```
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = null;
    if (bm.getReminderNotify().equals("Y")
            && currentMonthExpense > budget) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        notificationCount = notificationCount + 1;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                BudgetAlarm.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("NotifyCount", notificationCount);
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationCount,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, pi);
    } else {
       notificationCount = notificationCount + 1;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                BudgetAlarm.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("NotifyCount", notificationCount);
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationCount,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mgr.cancel(pi);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry again but what should I do with this?

Comment: Just replace it in your old code where you were setting the alarm manager

Comment: Nope, it does not work. The alarm manager still executing. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Any ideas? Cause I am still not able to solve it yet

Comment: Okay thanks! But do you have any idea on how to do for the post above?

Comment: Because everytime when I launch the apps, it will prompt notification. I wonder is there any way to still set the alarm manager but only prompt one notification per day regardless on how many times I launch the apps