# Android Running SQL statement in background

Tags: java, android, sql, date, alarmmanager

I am having some trouble with Alarm manager in Android. What I've encountered is when I set the alarm to repeat for every single minute, it works:

```
mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, pi);
```

However, when I try to set it to run the notification once per day, it does not work:

```
mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

This is the part where I execute the Alarm manager. This method was called at onCreate:

```
public void buildListView() {
    // Database part to retrieve the data

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        notificationCount = notificationCount + 1;
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                ReminderAlarm.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("RecurID", recurID);    
        notificationIntent.putExtra("RecurStartDate", recurDate);   
        notificationIntent.putExtra("CurrentDate", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        notificationIntent.putExtra("Description", recurDesc);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("Type", recurType);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("Amount", formatAmount);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("CategoryName", categoryName);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("Frequency", frequency);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("NotifyCount", notificationCount);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                notificationCount, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

And from the method above, it will call a receiver:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
    if (i.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        int notificationCount = Integer.parseInt(i.getExtras()
                .get("NotifyCount").toString());
        scheduleAlarms(context,notificationCount);
    }
}

static void scheduleAlarms(Context context, int notificationCount) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, notificationCount,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
}
```

}

Then from the bootReceiver class, it will call the alarmReminder class to do the SQL statement and prompt notification:

```
public class ReminderAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private Notification notification;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    //Getting all the data from extras

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(recurStartDate));
        if (frequencyStr.equals("Daily")) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            nextPaymentDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTimeInMillis());
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        } else if (frequencyStr.equals("Weekly")) {
            cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
            nextPaymentDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTimeInMillis());
            cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
        } 
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // If dates match then execute the SQL statements
    if (currentDate.equals(nextPaymentDate)) {
        DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(
                context.getApplicationContext());
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        mDbHelper.open();
        TransactionRecModel trm = new TransactionRecModel();
        CategoryController cc = new CategoryController(mDbHelper.open());

        trm.setDate(currentDate);
        trm.setTransDescription(description);
        trm.setType(type);
        trm.setAmount(Float.parseFloat(amount));

        // Get the categoryID based on categoryName
        String catID = cc.getCatIDByName(categoryName);
        trm.setCategory(catID);

        // Check if the recurring record exists before insert new
        // transaction record
        RecurringController rc1 = new RecurringController(mDbHelper.open());
        boolean recurExist = rc1.checkRecurExist(recurStartDate,
                description, catID);
        if (recurExist == true) {
            TransactionRecController trc = new TransactionRecController(
                    mDbHelper.open());
            // Check if the transaction record exists to prevent
            // duplication
            boolean moveNext = trc.checkTransExist(trm);
            if (moveNext == false) {

                if (trc.addTransactionRec(trm)) {
                    // Update recurring start date after insertion of
                    // transaction
                    RecurringModel rm = new RecurringModel();
                    rm.setRecurringID(recurID);
                    rm.setRecurringStartDate(currentDate);

                    RecurringController rc = new RecurringController(
                            mDbHelper.open());
                    if (rc.updateRecurringDate(rm)) {
                        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent
                                .getActivity(context, Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras()
                                        .get("NotifyCount").toString()), new Intent(), 0);
                        notification = new Notification(
                                R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Notification",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        notification
                                .setLatestEventInfo(context, description,
                                        nextPaymentDate, contentIntent);
                        mNotificationManager.notify(
                                Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras()
                                        .get("NotifyCount").toString()),
                                notification);
                        mDbHelper.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The strange thing is when I set it to repeat for every single minute, it works and execute the insert and update SQL in my reminderAlarm class. However, when I set it back to run once per day, it does not work. I wonder which part of my codes went wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you test it? Can you try to use `setExactRepeating()` function?

Comment: I tested it by adding recurring record yesterday. But up until today, it does not execute my insert and update SQL statement in reminderAlarm class until I manually launch the apps. it supposed to run in background

Comment: You can check it by changing the devices time settings. You don't have to wait 1 day I guess.

Comment: @tasomaniac I thought it runs based on the Calendar? So changing the date from device setting works? But basically if I test it with one minute, it runs perfectly. I not sure why it does not run properly when I change it to once per day

Comment: @tasomaniac Would you mind to be more specific or pin point the part which I did wrongly? Because I really have no idea why it behaved in this way.

Comment: I really don't know. What I suggest is that you can test more easily with changing time settings. It maybe related with the state of you app. Are you sure that it will change SQL even when your app is completely closed?

Comment: @tasomaniac I thought I was doing the SQL statement in alarm manager class which means it would run in background?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the alarm with 1 min interval by closing the application, and check whether the DB insertion is happening or not?

Also can you try changing:

```
DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(context.getApplicationContext());
```

with

```
DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(context);
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried with 1 and 5 minute. Firstly, I set a recurring tasks. After that, I close the apps. Does that counted as closing the apps? The strange thing is the DB insertion only runs when I launch the apps, it won't run for the timer that I've set for alarm manager

Comment: I've tested a lots of times. I realized that there is one problem. Let's say I set the recurring repeat every two hours, for every single time, the one minute after I set the tasks, it will execute the DB insertion. Then after that, I cleared the transaction record and change the time setting of my device, it runs again perfectly. But let's say I set it to once per day, the one minute after I set the tasks will not prompt any notification which mean the DB insertion is not executed because different date. For the next day, it won't run.

Comment: So in another words, if it does not execute the DB insertion for the one minute I set it, it wont run. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: if the db insertion is working for the 1 or 2 min of intervals, then I don't see any reason why it didn't work for 1 day interval.

Comment: It runs in a very weird manner. Let's say I set a recurring task on 03/10//2014. It supposed to execute the DB insertion on 04/10/2014 12.01AM. But somehow, it's delayed by one day which is 05/10/2014 but all the DB insertion and update works perfectly. Do you have any ideas?